# show message on qtextedit from c function

Tags: c++, c, qt, api

I try to show a message on qtextedit from c function.
I using an api class to call **qthello** method from c function.
**qthello** method has two staement.
qDebug statement Properly implemented and showed "hellooooooooo" . but **textEdit->setText("Hello");**  expression did not work.
what is wrong?

project.pro

```
QT        += widgets
TEMPLATE  += app
SOURCES   += \
main.cpp \
mainwindow.cpp \
hello.c \
api.cpp
HEADERS += \
mainwindow.h \
hello.h \
api.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "hello.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
hello();  //c function
w.show();
return a.exec();
}
```

hello.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

void hello(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

hello.c

```
#include "hello.h"
void hello(void){
char * s = "hellooooooooo";
//write(1, s, strlen(s));

void* myclass = MyClass_create();
MyClass_qthello(myclass , s);
MyClass_release(myclass);
}
```

api.h

```
#ifndef API_H
#define API_H
extern "C" void * MyClass_create();
extern "C" void MyClass_release(void* myclass);
extern "C" void MyClass_qthello(void* myclass , char * s);
#endif // API_H
```

api.cpp

```
#include "api.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
void * MyClass_create() {
return new MainWindow;
}
void MyClass_release(void* myclass) {
delete static_cast<MainWindow*>(myclass);
}
void MyClass_qthello(void* myclass , char * s) {
static_cast<MainWindow*>(myclass)->qthello(s);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
 void qthello(char * s);
private:
QTextEdit * textEdit;
};
#endif
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent):
QMainWindow(parent)
{
textEdit = new QTextEdit(this);
this->setCentralWidget(textEdit);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}

void MainWindow::qthello(cahr * s)
{
QString  str=s;
qDebug()<<str; //worked
textEdit->setText(str); // did not work
}
```

Comment: How did `cahr` get into your MCVE?

Comment: Also, for an MCVE you should put everything into a single `.cpp` file, include the module-wide header (here: `#include <QtWidgets>`), forgo include guards (it's a `.cpp` file after all), etc.

Comment: I do not get any error. I want to know why the first statement in the function qthello was executed but the second does not work ?

Comment: The first comment above is pointing out that "cahr" can't possibly compile, so your code here isn't actually real and it calls into question whether we're seeing the same thing you're working with. Besides the extremely convoluted mess of trying to do this, I don't see anything wrong with the textEdit->setText (str) call. What does the textEdit show before and after this call? Is there any changed at all?

Comment: what does "cahr mean? this is all of my code. when i called qthello method from MainWindow constructor, textedit showed message but when i called it from c function just qdebug worked and textedit did not show message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem . I used two different object (MainWindow object)

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication a(argc, argv);
//MainWindow w;
//w.makeWindow();
//w.show();
hello();
return a.exec();
}
```

hello.c

```
#include "hello.h"
void hello(void){
char * s = "hellllllllllllllllllloooo\n";
MyClass_create(s);
}
```

api.cpp

```
#include "api.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
void * MyClass_create(char * s) {
MainWindow * a = new MainWindow;
a->show();
a->qthello(s);
}
```

now, it working.